# How can i check which process use the mount ntfs

Tags: mount

I mounted one disk with `/etc/fstab`, however the process `mount-ntfs` is using a lot of CPU.

I checked with `iotop` but it also shows the `mount-ntfs` process so I can't find what is the true process that's using the `mount-ntfs` to write on the disk.

How can I check what process is using the `mount-ntfs`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try to use `fuser` or `lsof`

Comment: If i run fuser -u -v on the directory i only get this: 

root     kernel mount (root)  /path/...

Comment: With lsof working thanks :) :P

Comment: Glad to help :) Have a nice day